# Override css from Pseudo class

Tags: html, css

I am not a designer, so thisquestion might sound dumb.

I can override `color` property from pseudo class but not padding.

Here is an example

html:

```
<p id="pid" class="pclass"></p>
```

css:

```
.pclass
{
    color:red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#pid:before
{
    content:'test  ';
    color:green !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s3eedaa/)

Comment: You don't use id selectors in CSS. This is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**

The styles you've applied from the pseudo-class are applied to the `content` only. Not to the actual element. You might think that `!important` is making the color to change, but that is not the case.

So, when you change the `color` from pseudo-class the color of the content i.e. `test` is changed. And the `padding-left` is applied to the `test` only not the `<p>` element.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4s3eedaa/1/)

Inspect the paragraph and notice the padding.

```css
.pclass {
  color: red;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.pclass:before {
  content: 'test';
  color: green;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="pid" class="pclass"></p>
```

**Solution**

To solve this issue you can set the `position` of the element to `relative` and use negative `left`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4s3eedaa/2/)

```css
.pclass {
  color: red;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.pclass:before {
  content: 'test';
  color: green;
  left: -20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p id="pid" class="pclass"></p>
```

Comment: I have learnt something today, thanks for the answer. Can't I override padding from here?

Answer (score 1):

use this may help you

```
#pid::before {
    left: -20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: + For giving solution

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the padding using the `#pid` selector: IDs have an higher precedence than classes:

```
.pclass {
  color:red;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#pid:before {
  content: 'test';
  color: green;
}
#pid {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

If you wish to keep the margin after the text added by `:before` you can add

```
padding-right: 20px;
```

to `#pid:before`.